# substring count in a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, palindrome

Given a string s of length n. we have to count the number of substrings in which character s[i] of given string is present, where character s[i] is a vowel.

example : In this string "coding", character 'o' is present in 10 substrings and character 'i' is present in 12 substrings. so total 22 is answer.

constraints: string size can be up to 10^5 and number of test cases can be up to 10^2.

Note: string may contain upper case or lower case letter.

I have written a c++ program for this. But it is giving time limit exceed. It is running fine for a smaller size of the string. Can anyone help me for actual and better logic for such type of question.,which can run for larger string size also.

My attempt:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;


int main() 
{
int t;
cin >> t;

while (t--)
 {
    int n,i;
    cin >> n;

    string str;
    cin >> str;


    unsigned long long int 
  sum=0,pp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='A' || str[i]=='e' || str[i]=='E' || str[i]=='i' || str[i]=='I' || str[i]=='o' || str[i]=='O' || str[i]=='u' || str[i]=='U')
        {
            pp=(i+1)*(n-i);
            sum=sum+pp;
        }

    }

    cout <<sum << '\n';
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you arrived at the conclusion that in the string "coding", *"character 'o' is present in 10 substrings"*? What are these 10 substrings?

Comment: What does this question have to do with *palindromes* ? Why do you require the user to input n ? What is the purpose of n ?

Comment: Sir 'o' is present in co,od,odi,odin,oding,codi,coding,coding,o,cod.

Comment: And in "codin". And I have to discount one of your two "coding"s.

Comment: While it's true that there are 10 substrings containing `o` and 12 substrings containing `i`, they are not all distinct: e.g. `odi` is counted in both these totals. Are you supposed to count such substrings twice? That's what you do when you just add up 10 and 12 and declare the total to be 22.

Comment: Yes sir they should be counted as separate.That's why I counted them twice.

Comment: The number of substrings that contain a character in position `i` (zero-based) is `(i+1) * (n-i)` (thus, in your example, `o` in position 1 belongs to `2*5==10` substrings; `i` in position 3 belongs to `4*3=12` substrings). With this in mind, you can easily compute the total in a single pass.

Comment: Sir I changed my code according to your logic but still getting wrong answer in every test case. Can u please check my above code?

Comment: Sir, I think may be some overflow condition arise, as size of string can be 10^5.

Answer (score 0):

Do not bruteforce. Do a combinatorics homework.

Hint #1: A string of length `n` has `n*(n+1)/2` substrings.

Hint #2: Vowels partition the original string into a set of substrings of consonants. A substring of consonants of length `k` in turn generates `k*(k+1)/2` substrings *which should not be counted*.

This should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Take example of coding, total substrings is 21 ,i.e n*(n+1)/2. Now set of partioned consonants are c, d, ng .so total number of substrings formed by them is 1+1+3=5 so number of substrings in which at least one vowel come is 21-5 =16.  But sir , answer is 22. Am I interpreting ur 2nd hint wrong?